# How can I make my page to stop entering "google deceptive site" whenever i upload it

Tags: php, forms, url, cross-site

My Site is always marked as deceptive site, I have tried everything I could to fix it but all efforts failed. I came across this word `cross-site scripting` while I was trying to research on-line.

The question is, could this(`cross-site scripting`) be the reason why my site is always seen as a malicious site? If Yes, how do I fix this?

Here's the form on my page:

```
<form action="proceesor.php">
    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="40" value="<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>"/><br>
    <input name="password" type="password" id="password" value="" size="40" maxlength="400"/><br>
    <input name="button" type="submit" value="Submit" id="button">
</form>
```

Comment: What's your site URL?

Comment: `echo $_GET['email']` is XSS injectible, escape that with `htmlspecialchars`.

Comment: The URL should look like: mydomain.com/index.php?email=test@yourmail.com

Comment: how do i do that (htmlspecialchars)...??

Comment: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['email']); ?>

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: What about the password field, does it require htmlspecialchars to be used on it...?

Comment: No, only where you are outputting data provided by the client. `proceesor.php` could be open to injections as well. For example try `mydomain.com/index.php?email=%22%20%2F%3E%3Cmarquee%3EInjected%3C%2Fmarquee%3E` (depending on your browser it might already reject this)